# ArrayFormula with VlookupS If one is blank then use second Vlookup in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use Vlookup in a Google Sheet using an ID to match 2 separate tables. If there is no match in the first table, then I am telling the code to search for it in the second table. The lookup value, and 2 tables are all in different sheets and it doesnt work but I am able to get another test to work when they are all on the same sheet so I am not sure why that is.

For example this works

```
arrayformula(IFERROR(if(vlookup(A2:A,D2:E,2,FALSE)<>"",vlookup(A2:A,D2:E,2,FALSE),vlookup(A2:A,G2:H,2,FALSE))))
```

| ID | Vlookup |  | ID | Vlookup value |  | ID | Vlookup value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | One |  | 1 | One |  | 1 |  |
| 2 | Two |  | 2 |  |  | 2 | Two |
| 3 | Three |  | 3 | Three |  | 3 |  |
| 4 | Four |  | 4 |  |  | 4 | Four |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

**This Full Formula fails**

```
Arrayformula(IFERROR(IF(vlookup($B$2:$B,Sheet1!$A$3:$I,4,FALSE)<>"",vlookup($B$2:$B,Sheet1!$A$3:$I,4,FALSE),vlookup($B$2:$B,'Sheet2'!$A$1:$N,4,FALSE))))
```

I'm not sure how to moidfy my formula, which works in individual parts and together it matches data in Sheet1! but not on Sheet 2! based on my tests.

**Testing Results**

1. `Arrayformula(IFERROR(IF(vlookup($B$2:$B,Sheet1!$A$3:$I,4,FALSE)` --> Vlookkup matches Sheet1! data also
2. `Arrayformula(vlookup($B$2:$B,'Sheet2'!$A$1:$N,4,FALSE)` -->matches Sheet2! data
3. Modify the second part of the data to "False"

Arrayformula(IFERROR(IF(vlookup($B$2:$B,Sheet1!$A$3:$I,4,FALSE)<>"",vlookup($B$2:$B,Sheet1!$A$3:$I,4,FALSE),"False"))))

Result: Anything that does not match in either Sheet 1 or Sheet 2 says "False". But a match in Sheet 1 works and a match in Sheet 2 shows blank.

4. Modifying the IF statements to make consistent did not work either

   Arrayformula(IFERROR(IF(vlookup($B$2:$B,Sheet1!$A$3:$I,4,FALSE)<>"",vlookup($B$2:$B,Sheet1!$A$3:$I,4,FALSE),
   IF(vlookup($B$2:$B,Sheet2!$A$1:$N,4,FALSE)<>"",vlookup($B$2:$B,Sheet2!$A$1:$N,4,FALSE),""))))

How can I modify the formula so that it works in unison?

Comment: it would help if you could share a sample editable sheet with demo data and expected output (manually done) so that we can work it out easily.

Comment: im going to do it in a table as advised prior not to share sheet

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
=arrayformula(IFERROR(if(vlookup(A2:A,Sheet1!A1:B5,2,FALSE)<>"",vlookup(A2:A,Sheet1!A1:B5,2,FALSE),vlookup(A2:A,Sheet2!A1:B5,2,FALSE))))
```

Still unsure if there is another error in the formula above that didn't work as I think it should have worked